# changing multiple column values given a condition in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking to find a simple way to do something like the following but with dplyr, essentially just replacing the values in 3 columns with NA when the condition is met.

```
dta[dta$na.ind == 1, c('x1', 'x2', 'x3')] <- NA
```

The only method I can think of using dplyr is the following, but I feel there should be a simpler way

```
dta <- dta %>% 
    mutate(x1 = ifelse(na.ind == 1, NA, x1),
           x2 = ifelse(na.ind == 1, NA, x2),
           x3 = ifelse(na.ind == 1, NA, x3))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `mutate_at` and pass the columns `x1,x2,x3` to `.vars` parameter:

```
dta <- data.frame(na.ind = 1:3, x1 = 2:4, x2 = 2:4, x3 = 2:4, x4 = 2:4)
dta
#  na.ind x1 x2 x3 x4
#1      1  2  2  2  2
#2      2  3  3  3  3
#3      3  4  4  4  4

dta %>% mutate_at(.vars = c("x1", "x2", "x3"), funs(ifelse(na.ind == 1, NA, .)))
#  na.ind x1 x2 x3 x4
#1      1 NA NA NA  2
#2      2  3  3  3  3
#3      3  4  4  4  4
```

Comment: `funs()` is soft deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0 and it is advised to use `~` instead:
`dta %>% mutate_at(c("x1", "x2", "x3"), ~ ifelse(na.ind == 1, NA, .)))`

Answer (score 6):

Since scoped verbs like `mutate_at`, `mutate_all` etc. are being replaced by `across`, you could now make the following adjustments to Psidom's answer:

```
> dta <- data.frame(na.ind = 1:3, x1 = 2:4, x2 = 2:4, x3 = 2:4, x4 = 2:4)
> dta
  na.ind x1 x2 x3 x4
1      1  2  2  2  2
2      2  3  3  3  3
3      3  4  4  4  4

> dta %>% mutate(across(c(x1, x2, x3), ~ ifelse(na.ind == 1, NA, .)))
  na.ind x1 x2 x3 x4
1      1 NA NA NA  2
2      2  3  3  3  3
3      3  4  4  4  4
```

See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html for more information on `across`.

Answer (score 2):

If you instead want a data.frame-wise replacement of a specific value (-99999) in any column for NA:

```
dta %>% mutate_all(funs(ifelse(.==-99999, NA, .)))
```

Update: `funs` is deprecated. The above code now is:

```
dta %>% mutate(across(c(x1, x2, x3), ~ ifelse(.==-99999, NA, .)))
```

Comment: `mutate_if` operates on all rows of columns passing the predicate, not on subsets of rows. For example, you can `mutate_if(dat, is.character, as.factor)`. Of course, if you insist on using `mutate_if`, it is possible: `mutate_if(dat, is.numeric, funs(ifelse(.==-99999, NA, .)))`

Comment: funs no longer works unfortunately as this solution was more intuitive than those below