# How do I replace values in a matrix from an uploaded CSV file in R?

Tags: r, matrix, replace, data-science, gsub

These are the steps I took:

1) Read in CSV file

```
rawdata <- read.csv('name of my file', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

2) Cleaned my data by removing certain records based on x-criteria

```
data <- rawdata[!(rawdata$YOURID==""), all()]
data <- data[(data$thiscolumn=="right"), all()]
data <- data[(data$thatcolumn=="right"), all()]
```

3)  Now I want to replace certain values throughout the whole matrix with a number (replace a string with a number value).  I have tried the following commands and nothing works (I've tried `gsub` and `replace`):

```
gsub("Not the right string", 2, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
data <- replace(data, data$thiscolumn == "Not the right string" , 2)
gsub("\\Not the right string", "2", data$thiscolumn, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

I am new to R.  I normally code in C++.  The only other thing for me to try is a for loop.  I potentially might only want R to look at certain columns for replace certain values, but I'd prefer a search through the whole matrix.  Either is fine.

These are the guidelines per R Help:

> sub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
>      gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
>
> replace(x, list, values)
>      Arguments
>      x     vector
>      list   an index vector
>      values replacement values

Example: I want to replace the text "Extremely Relevant 5" or whatever x-text, with a corresponding number value.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing csv file into R - numeric values read as characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706188/importing-csv-file-into-r-numeric-values-read-as-characters)

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute the `for` loop by using logical indexing. First you need to identify the indices of what you want to replace, then assign the new value for these indices.

Here's small example. Let's say we have this vector:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 99, 4, 2, 99)
# x
# [1]  1  2 99  4  2 99
```

And we want to find all places where it's 99 and replace it with 0. when you apply `x == 99` you get a `TRUE` and `FALSE` vector.

```
x == 99
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

You can use this vector as an index to assign the new value where the condition is met.

```
x[x == 99] <- 0
# x
# [1] 1 2 0 4 2 0
```

Similarly you can use this approach to apply it across a dataframe or a matrix in a one-shot

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(2, 99, 3), col2 = c(99, 4, 99))
# df:
#   col1 col2
# 1    2   99
# 2   99    4
# 3    3   99

df[df==99] <- 0
# df
#   col1 col2
# 1    2    0
# 2    0    4
# 3    3    0
```

For dataframe with strings, it might be trickier since the column can be factor and the value you're trying to replace is not one of the levels. You can go around that by changing it to `character` and apply the replacement.

```
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c(2, "this string", 3), col2 = c("this string", 4, "this string"))
> df
         col1        col2
1           2 this string
2 this string           4
3           3 this string
> sapply(df, class)
    col1     col2 
"factor" "factor" 

> df <- sapply(df, as.character)
> df
     col1          col2         
[1,] "2"           "this string"
[2,] "this string" "4"          
[3,] "3"           "this string"

> df[df == "this string"] <- 0
> df <- as.data.frame(df)
> df
  col1 col2
1    2    0
2    0    4
3    3    0
```

Comment: data <- [data=="String of Interest"] <- 5 //Does not work

Comment: I want to be able to match a string in every entry and replace it with a numerical value.  Any insight?

Comment: I tried your code matching a numerical value and replacing with a numerical value (and it works), but I want to find "this string" in every record and replace it with a number.

Comment: it is data[data=="String of Interest"] <-5, not data <- [data=="String of Interest"] <- 5

Comment: @Becca Updated the answer to include a string example and what might be the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have found a few solutions to my own questions I thought I'd share in just working a little more out just now.

1)  I had to add the package "library(stringr)" at the top so that R can understand matching strings.

2) I used a for loop to go down the entries of a specific column I wanted in my Matrix to change to the value indicated. See as follows:

```
`#possible solution 5 - This totally works!
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if (data$columnofinterest[i] == "String of Interest")
  data$columnofinterest[i] <- "Becca is da bomb dot com"
}`

`#possible solution 6 - This totally works!
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if (data$columnofinterest[i] == "Becca is da bomb dot com")
  data$columnofinterest[i] <- 7
}`
```

As you can see replacing specific records between text and a numerical value is 
possible (text to numerical value and vice versa).  And as the comments indicate it took me till the 5 and 6 problem solution to figure this much out.  Still not the whole Matrix, but at least I can go through column of interest at a time, which is 
still a lot faster.`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr`/`tidyverse` solution adapted from [changing multiple column values given a condition in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888008/changing-multiple-column-values-given-a-condition-in-dplyr).  You can use `mutate_all`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(a = c("don't change", "change", "don't change"),
               b = c("change", "Change", "don't change"))

data %>%
  mutate_all(funs(if_else(. == "change", "xxx", .)))
```

Comment: Awesome.  I am currently taking some dplyr tutorials so I am better versed in them. I have another side question just in case you know the answer...  I have already installed plyr and dplyr packages in the past when running Rstudio.  However every time I start a new session of r it makes me redownload those packages or the code I use from dplyr and plyr do not work.  Is that normal that I have to download these packages every time?

Comment: That doesn't seem normal--you should just have to call the package with `library`.

Comment: That's what I thought!  I learned that the specific problem I was having is because the MASS and dplyr conflict with each other.  They both have "select" and which ever one was ran first is the select function that will be used.  It's not like C++ where I can list all the libraries I will ever need at the top and run them with every session.  I can only run the exact libraries I need at the time or else some will conflict with others.  Learning something new every day!!! @Ben G