# How to replace values in multiple columns according to conditions in R

Tags: r, replace, mutate

I am having trouble writing a code that would replace all specified values in multiple columns with new values. The data frame has 20+ columns and I only want to change values in 8 columns  (col1, col2, col3, etc). I want to replace all values (4, 5, 6, 7) with (0, -1, -2, -3) respectively. I have very limited knowledge in R and progamming and I have only been able to get a solution that would do the job for one column.

I have read so many solutions to similar questions on here but I could find a solution that works for me. So here is my code:

```
data$col1[raw_data$col1 == 4 ] <- 0
data$col1[raw_data$col1 == 5 ] <- -1
data$col1[raw_data$col1 == 6] <- -2
data$col1[raw_data$col1 == 7] <- -3
```

So this works well for one column. can I possibly do it one for all columns?

here is a snippet of how the columns and values are:
[image: dataframe]

Comment: just a note - the existing columns are numeric but your replacements are strings - you don't need the `" "` around the new values.

Comment: You could take a look at `dplyr::across` and `dplyr::case_when`.

Comment: @Julian do you have any pointer? For example, I have used this example but I cannot figure out how to specify all my columns and the 4 conditions according to this example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42888008/changing-multiple-column-values-given-a-condition-in-dplyr]

Comment: In your example the change is actually quite straightforward - it's just `4-x` if x is 4, 5, 6, or 7 - see my answer below.

Comment: Based on comments on the existing answers I think your data set needs cleaning up first - convert any columns to the appropriate data type (integer, double, string) etc so it is clearer what you are working with, decide how to deal with NA entries (and check they are real `NA` not strings like `"N/A"`)

Comment: I have cleaned my data and removed the missing values. Now I have all the numeric values. I am no longer getting the error nor are the values being replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up an example:

```
demodf <- data.frame(
  col1 = 1:10,
  col2 = 3:12,
  col3 = 5:14,
  col4 = 7:16
)

cols_to_amend <- c("col1", "col3")
```

replace just the relevant columns:

```
demodf[cols_to_amend] <- apply(demodf[cols_to_amend], 2, FUN = \(x) sapply(x, \(y) if (y %in% 4:7) 4-y else y))
```

gives:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4
1     1    3   -1    7
2     2    4   -2    8
3     3    5   -3    9
4     0    6    8   10
5    -1    7    9   11
6    -2    8   10   12
7    -3    9   11   13
8     8   10   12   14
9     9   11   13   15
10   10   12   14   16
```

### Explanation:

```
# we can use the list of column names to choose where we are replacing
demodf[cols_to_amend]
# we then use `apply` and `MARGIN = 2` to apply a function to each column in this data frame:
 <- apply(demodf[cols_to_amend], 2,
# The function we apply will be an anonymous function (`\( )`) taking as its input one column at a time:
FUN = \(x)
# and it will use `sapply` to go down that column performing the following on each item:
\(y) if (y %in% 4:7) 4-y else y)
```

### dplyr version:

```
library(dplyr)

demodf |> 
  mutate(
    across(all_of(cols_to_amend),
           ~ ifelse(.x %in% 4:7, 4-.x, .x)
           )
    )
```

### dplyr version 2

Excessive complexity for this toy example, but allowing for more complex replacements than simple math:

```
demodf |> 
  mutate(
    across(all_of(cols_to_amend),
           ~ case_when(.x == 4 ~ 0,
                       .x == 5 ~ -1,
                       .x == 6 ~ -2,
                       .x == 7 ~ -3,
                       .default = .x)
           )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, but am having an error: Error in 4 - y : non-numeric argument for binary operator.

Comment: Ah, your values must be stored as strings (text) not numbers, or possibly you have missing values?

Comment: I have n/a values and I added na.omit(data1) but its still not working.

Comment: @NampaGwakondo Can you use `dput()` to get an exact copy of your data and edit into your original question as a code block please?  It will allow a more robust answer.  See here for help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/16730940

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the corresponding column names you want to modify, and it should work.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:5,
  col1 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  col2 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  col3 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  col4 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  col5 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  col6 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  col7 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  col8 = c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
)

# Specify the columns you want to modify
columns_to_modify <- c("col5", "col6", "col7")

# Specify a replacement function for the corresponding values

my_fun_replace <- \(vec){
  case_match(
    vec,
    4 ~ 0,
    5 ~ -1,
    6 ~ -2,
    7 ~ -3,
    .default = vec
  )
  
}


# Use across to replace values in specified columns
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(columns_to_modify), my_fun_replace))
```

Comment: Good one.. I completely understand the syntax but I have an error: ```Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `col2`.
Caused by error in `case_match()`:
! Can't convert `..1 (left)` <double> to <character>.```

Comment: An error with this repex ? Humm... I use dplyr version 1.1.3. Maybe it comes from the class of your variables. Try `class(df$col5)` to verify it is a proper numeric variable ?

Comment: It was because of the missing values. I have cleaned the data and removed the rows with missing values. However, the replacement is still not taking place. No error and no change to the original values.

Comment: No idea... Could you please give a reproducible example of this ? At least, does my example work properly from your session ?